# Showing an image inside Material Progress Spinner

Tags: angular-material, material-design, spinner, angular7, progress

I want to add to my Angular 7 project a material progress spinner and an image of a person in it; indicating the vote percentage the person received. For now, I couldn't do it. Any way to handle? Or is there any alternative spinner library you know handling this use-case?

Here is an image representation of what I need:

[image: image inside material progress spinner]

Thank you.

Comment: please see my answer, hope its helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate css `clip-path: circle(45% at 50% 49%);` property to adjust the image around your spinner.

```
//------component.css
.basic-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  clip-path: circle(45% at 50% 49%);
}

//------component.html
<div class="basic-container">
    <mat-spinner strokeWidth="2" [diameter]="100"></mat-spinner>
    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg">
</div>
```

**[Demo showing image inside Angular Material Spinner](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-progress-spinner-with-image-inside?file=app/app.component.html)**

Comment: A bit playing with your code gave the results. Thank you.

Comment: @ArdaOğulÜçpınar glad, i could help.

Comment: But I could not stop the spinner. It always spins, even when its mode set to determinate :/

Comment: Ok. To stop it I should use `mat-progress-spinner` instead of `mat-spinner`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a css class to your mat-spinner:

CSS:

```
avatar {
    background-image: url(https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/avatar-372-456324.png);
    animation: none;
    background-size: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px
}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-spinner class="avatar"></mat-spinner>
```

If you want to show different avatar every time, you can add `style`

```
<mat-spinner class="avatar" style="background-image: url({{myImageUrl}}></mat-spinner>
```

Comment: It really works but works -a bit- much. Avatar is spinning with the spinner :)

Comment: Look at the css code, prop `animation: none` should stop image spinning, but it changes a little bit spinner as well :)